# Данные пользователя

Tags: php

Подскажите, как на PHP, вывести на экран (Echo или Print) данные пользователя, такие как 
IP, браузер, скорость соединения. Не понимаю, это переменные и какие значения берутся у пользователя. Какие можно еще взять данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
    printr($_SERVER);
?>
```

А дальше и сами поймете.

Comment: Согласен $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] // IP адрес
         $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] // UserAgent => браузер
Но "printr($_SERVER)" выдаст все переданное пользователем!

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] // IP адрес
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] // UserAgent => браузер
```

Answer (score 1):

Исчерпавающая информация:
[Суперглобальный массив $_SERVER](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=vars&page=015)